# how to change permalink after creating website

Tags: wordpress

I am using default **permalink** and my website is ready for launch.

Now client want **permalink** to be changed.

I follow the step to change the **permalink**. But site stop working if I change the **permalink**.

How can I change the **permalink** without disturbing the site.

Many Thanks

Comment: When you say you're wantinig to change your permalink, what is the context. Is this WordPress?

Comment: @Just a guy - Doesn't the tag say so?

Comment: Ah yes. That it does. I tend to miss the smaller details in the late hours

Comment: Yes it is wordpress

right now it is default.
http://192.168.3.52/iskcon_src/?page_id=102

I want to change it

Answer (score 1):

You will have to edit your `.htaccess` file and add the mod_rewrite rule. In the Permalinks page, at the bottom, Wordpress will give you the content you need to enter.

Answer (score 0):

In latest WordPress, your .htaccess file will be auto updated. Though if it doesn't, change your htaccess permission to 777 and then try changing permalink. once it's done, you can change your .htaccess permission back to 644.
Here is a tutorial: [Changing WordPress Permalink](http://wpfreesetup.com/86/how-to-change-wordpress-permalink-with-301-perma-redirection/)